# git show file encoding gbk abnormal

Tags: git, cygwin

My git repo's file encoding is `gbk`, and I use git in `Cygwin`.
When I use `git show` or `git diff`, comments in file show abnormal.

How can I configure git.

Comment: In my project git's commit log's encoding is urf-8, but my file in repo is using gbk. git's commit log show in bash is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ***`git diff`*** you can use [***`git-diff-tree`***](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree)

## ***`git show --encoding`*** / ***`git diff-tree --encoding`***

> ***`--encoding[=<encoding>]`***
>
> The commit objects record the `encoding` used for the log message in their encoding header;
>
> this option can be used to tell the command to `re-code` the commit log message **in the encoding preferred by the user**.
> For non plumbing commands this defaults to **`UTF-8`**.

Comment: But it did not work for me. In my project, file's encoding is gbk, a lot of comments in file is chinese words. And git commit message used utf-8. When I use 'git diff', it show Chinese words, like '<BD><DF>'